# How can I accurately and precisely measure current in a 110 VAC circuit with a 1 kΩ-50 kΩ load using an oscilloscope?

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, grounding, shunt, transimpedance

I need to measure the electrical resistance of a volume of ground.

To do this I need to cause a current to flow between two metal electrodes pushed into the soil (let's call them the "current" electrodes) and measure the potential difference created by this flow using a second set of electrodes connected to a voltmeter (lets call them the "voltage" electrodes).

Since the charge between the current electrodes causes ions in the soil-water to accumulate around the electrodes I need to use an alternating square-wave current source (in the 50-150 Hz range - low enough so we don't get problems with complex impedance). And since I'm interested in the way in which the voltage between my measurement electrodes changes over time I will use an oscilloscope to make my measurements - which must therefore be voltages in a reasonable range (1 mV to 10 V).

The ratio of the current flowing between the injecting electrodes to the voltage between the measurement electrodes gives me a "resistance" value using Ohm's law and a simple geometric modification. And that solves my original problem.

I can use an off-the-shelf 12 VDC to 110 VAC square-wave "mains" converter to supply the voltage to drive the square-wave alternating current powered by a simple 12 V battery. 110 V is high, I know, but the contact resistance of the electrodes with the soil is in the 1 kΩ to 50 kΩ range and to get a current flow high enough to measure with precision (at least 1 mA) I need to drive the current with a voltage of tens to hundreds of volts - one commercial system I own uses voltages as high as 800 V to measure ground resistance, though a 100 V maximum is more common.

The current will still be too low to measure precisely using a Hall-effect current sensor  so I need an alternative.

So here's my problem: The off-the-shelf circuits I can buy to measure small current accurately and precisely, by conversion to a voltage of reasonable range, are DC only, but the current flowing into the ground must be square-wave AC. So what simple circuit, perhaps a version of a shunt-plus-amplifier, can I use to convert the AC current to an equivalent (zero-crossing) AC voltage measurement in the <+/-10 V range my oscilloscope can accept, without significantly affecting the current itself?

Comment: How accurate, and how precise, do you want?

Comment: Explaining what and why would help. Ground resistance will vary with electrodes used and soil characteristics not just in straight line between the electrodes. | If you've not met them look up curviilinear 
 squares and the 3D equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Edited because of new information in a later comment)

As your after a 4 wire measurement, lets begin by lowering the voltage to be within the safe range of your scope

For a 4 wire measurment you can either know the current your sourcing, and measure a voltage, or know the voltage and measure a current, due to the application, measuring the voltage will be much easier

Lets start with say a 6.3V transformer, its peak voltage will be within your scopes ability, (about 9V peak), we only need to know the amount of current so we will use a current shunt resistor to measure it, as the current will be low due to the resistance of the soil we will keep it rather high, lets say about 10K,

1 scope probe attaches across this current shunt and gets the current via measuring a voltage, now the scope probe will shift this value slightly due to acting like a 1M or 10M resistor in parrellel, but the effect can be calculated out.

So 1 probe to 1 side of the transformer, 1 probe via the current shunt to the other side, and we have out "Source" probes

Next up the measure, due to the small amount of current, we will use amplification to make up for it. using a "differential amplifier", these have a fun side bonus that its easy to choose what voltage is outputs that difference against, you will need to provide power to this device, so may need to build a small rectifier and capacitor to feed it DC voltage off the same transformer

The relationship for the gap between the probes is important so you may wish to mount these 2 measure probes on something to keep them a fixed distance apart.

the second scope channel measures the differential output, and you have a voltage, and a current, leaving you with a resistance,

The input voltage minus the measurement voltage is then the soil voltage, you know the current based on the measurement voltage leaving a simple calculation for its resistance

[Falstad Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%207.010541234668786%2050%205%2043%0Av%20-32%2096%20-32%20240%200%201%2060%207%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-32%2096%20192%2096%200%0Ar%20-32%20240%20192%20240%200%2015000%0Aw%20192%2096%20224%2096%200%0A174%20224%20208%20256%20160%201%2050000%200.9356000000000001%20Soil%20Resistance%0Ap%20192%20272%20-32%20272%201%200%0Aw%20-32%20272%20-32%20240%200%0Aw%20192%20272%20192%20240%200%0Ap%20896%20304%20896%20448%201%200%0Aw%20-32%20448%20896%20448%200%0Aw%20-32%20448%20-32%20352%200%0Ax%201787%20318%201886%20321%205%2016%20Current%5CsShunt%0Ax%2032%20213%20131%20216%204%2016%20Current%5CsShunt%0Ax%20287%20182%20313%20185%204%2016%20Soil%0Ax%2040%20297%20112%20300%204%2016%20Channel%5Cs1%0Ax%20925%20408%20997%20411%204%2016%20Channel%5Cs2%0Ax%20-144%20276%20-41%20279%204%2016%20Scope%5CsGround%0Ar%20272%20144%20272%2096%200%205000%0Ar%20272%20208%20272%20256%200%205000%0Aw%20192%20240%20272%20256%200%0Aw%20224%2096%20272%2096%200%0Aw%20272%20144%20800%20224%200%0Aw%20272%20208%20576%20224%200%0Ar%20432%20304%20576%20304%200%20100000%0Aa%20576%20240%20688%20240%209%2015%20-15%201000000%20-4.2549675348551235%20-4.2549936493769%20100000%0Aw%20576%20256%20576%20272%200%0Ar%20576%20304%20688%20304%200%20100000%0Aw%20576%20272%20576%20304%200%0Aw%20688%20304%20688%20240%200%0Aa%20800%20240%20896%20240%209%2015%20-15%201000000%20-0.4108902073951968%20-0.4108723106775685%20100000%0Ar%20688%20304%20800%20304%200%20100000%0Ar%20800%20304%20896%20304%200%20100000%0Aw%20896%20304%20896%20240%200%0Aw%20800%20304%20800%20256%200%0Aw%20432%20304%20432%20352%200%0Aw%20432%20352%20-32%20352%200%0Aw%20-32%20352%20-32%20272%200%0Aw%20224%20208%20272%20208%200%0Aw%20256%20176%20272%20176%200%0Aw%20272%20176%20272%20144%200%0Ab%20206%2062%20324%20300%200%0Ao%205%2064%200%204098%205%200.1%200%201%0Ao%208%2064%200%204098%2010%200.1%200%201%0A)

Now this is a not so normally used differential amplifier design, but it is one of my favorites for high impedance work, as for a specific op amp, you want one that can handle atleast +-10V (overkill but much harder to damage) sadly its getting late, so none are coming to mind.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Reroute - but what is undoubtedly a very helpful answer doesn't tell me enough for me to understand. That's my fault, no doubt, but could you clarify?

Comment: Lower the voltage of what? Increase the resistance where and how? etc.

Comment: Can you suggest where I can see a circuit diagram to help me out? Thanks

Comment: Unless it is a battery powered scope, I don't think that you should connect the scope ground to the excitation voltage. The scope ground is also connected to earth ground at the main breaker panel and this may affect the measurement. Use 2 probes in differential (subtraction) mode for all your measurements.

Comment: I was working under the assumption of a transformer output, due to the low voltage,

Comment: Thank you, Mattman944 and Reroute. I'll think this through. Perhaps I've misunderstood but the reason we use two separate circuits - one to inject a current and one to measure a potential - and then calculate the ratio of the two is that almost all the resistance in the circuits arise because of the contact resistance between the electrodes and the soil, not the resistance of the soil itself (which is what I need to measure). I'd rather assumed that, since this is a crucial element of Earthing practice it was common knowledge among you clever electronics people.

Comment: Thus a single circuit which measures the whole resistance of the ground, contact resistance included, doesn't meet my needs. The four-electrode system is in common use. It's how, for example, the "Earth resistance" instruments made by my excellent colleagues at Megger work. Now, from what I see the circuit you've suggested, Reroute, doesn't separate the contact resistance from the soil's inherent resistance. Is that correct? Can you see why I need a different solution with a direct measurement of current flow between the current electrodes?

Comment: Then we can seperate it, if you really wish to go with this path the circuit changes a little and you will need to amplify the signal from the 2 "measure" probes, 

The driving circuit remains, you loose the current shunt, and channel 1,

Comment: Instead you have a "differential amplifier" across the 2 measurement probes, and by outputing this against circuit ground you have your resistance for the distance between the probes, I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much - I appreciate your comments. It isn't that I "wish to go down this path" but the measurement of soil resistance can only be realistically made in this way (unless we look at EMI approaches - and that gives us a rather different measurement).

Comment: The problem here is that the rheostat you've defined to represent the soil has much to high a resistance set. The two resistors representing the contact resistance have realistic values of 5K but the soil itself will typically have a resistance in the 10-200 Ohm range, not the 47K you've set here. If I reduce the soil resistance to say 100 Ohms I get almost no voltage at channel 2. Pushing the voltage supply back up to my original 110v and fidling with other values solves the problem but I'm sure it's not optimal. Further thoughts? Thanks again

Comment: Simply reduce the value of the current shunt, however remeber you are measuring the current with that contact resistance in series, as such it will be higher resistance than the soil. 

The measure probes have a gain of 2, and can have a higher gain if needed,

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid but why is it a good idea to reduce the voltage driving the current between the current electrodes? The drop from 110v to 6.7v will greatly reduce the voltage measured between the voltage electrodes. I get that we can amplify the signal back up using the two op amps but why doesn't this also greatly amplify noise? I've been struggling with this and I just can't see how you circuit avoids creating a very noisy signal. Is there another reason to drop the voltage?

Comment: I was hoping to reduce the risk of you damaging the input, tell me the model of your scope, it could well be that with a probe connected the input range is actually much higher, If you want to bump up the exitation voltage, then you will need to make sure that the current shunt voltage cannot exceed that safe limit, e.g. you have wet soil with much better contact resistance, at a minimum, stay under 70V AC, as that is where the risks start approaching lethal levels for electrocution.

Comment: I certainly need to avoid destroying the scope (a Picoscope 5242D) but the voltages your circuit shows at the two channels are not great and I can reduce them both to within a +/-2V range by picking the right shunt and op-amp values/configuration. or have I misunderstood? The whole reason for using higher voltages is that the soil is often going to be dry and the resistance therefore high. So to get a voltage high enough to measure between the voltage electrodes without being overwhelmed by noise-voltages in the soil I need to drive a fair amount of current.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for my health but typical (top-end) commercial systems use voltages as high as 800v (I own one of these), while "ordinary" systems can provide voltage as high as 100v though typically stay below 50v.

Comment: Ok, there we go, hook up an X10 probe and your safe to +-200V, (check the probes rating, but most should be rated for about 300V RMS)

Comment: Thank you. It's been really good to think through the issues with your help.